# update dictionary in javascrips from array of objects in efficient way

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following response from API  :

I need to update the dictionary without run all over the array 
is an efficient way to do that?

before going this response I got an array of "get all" and convert the array to dictionary so it will be easier to update the list

```
[
  {id:2, name:"rrr"},
  {id:3 , name:"test"}
]
```

and I have the following Dictionary:

```
0: {id:0, name:"aaa"},
1: {id:1, name:"bbb"},
2: {id:2, name:"rrr"},
3: {id:3, name:"zzz"},
```

result of mergind the data is updated the Dictionary with the new object (replace the object)
the key of dictionary is the same like "id" param

so result will be ;

```
0: {id:0, name:"aaa"},
1: {id:1, name:"bbb"},
2: {id:2, name:"rrr"},
3: {id:3, name:"test"},
```

Comment: what is the expected output and condition based on which api response to be updated

Comment: Can you give in brief what is the data you need to manipulate and what's the resultant data you need?

Comment: Hi @chaitanya i added an example, i just need to merge the array into dictiornary and replace by id

Comment: Will your API response consists all the objects in your other dictionary or only some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this.

Using the array.prototype.map function to loop over the entire response array and map it out to a custom object in the format you desire.

```
let dictionary = {};
    array.map(function(item) {
        dictionary[item.id] = item
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash, I would use something like this.

```js
const dict = {
  0: {id:0, name:"aaa"},
  1: {id:1, name:"bbb"},
  2: {id:2, name:"rrr"},
  3: {id:3, name:"zzz"}
};

const expected = {
  0: {id:0, name:"aaa"},
  1: {id:1, name:"bbb"},
  2: {id:2, name:"rrr"},
  3: {id:3, name:"test"}
}

// data from xhr response
const xhrResponse = [
  {id:2, name:"rrr"},
  {id:3, name:"test"}
];

// 
_.merge(
  dict,                       // merge into dict
  _.keyBy(xhrResponse, 'id')  // the result of the keyBy function
);

console.log(`Actua ${_.isEqual(expected, dict) ? '' : 'NOT' } equals expected`)

console.log(dict);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```